# how to get json data in jquery var?

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get grid on view, for this I am using the jqgrid. and my action controller methods is returning me json data. I want to pick this data up in the 'var. in jquery. I am using asp.net mvc. how can i get this I tried :

```
$.getJSON(url:gridDataUrl,{}, function(jsonData) {
  alert(jsonData);
});
);
```

Where gridDataUrl having my action url.
how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method signature is

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, [data], [callback(data, textStatus, xhr)])
```

...so it should look like this:

```
$.getJSON(gridDataUrl, function(jsonData) {
  alert(jsonData);
});
```

Note that the first param is the URL as just a string (not a label) and that both `data` and the callback are optional (denoted by `[]` in the signature).  The above should only alert `[object Object]` though, since it's the overall object...you'll need `jsonData.propertyName` for example to get something meaningful out.

Comment: no it is not working, is i have to enclose this code in function ?

Comment: @Lalit - this should work anywhere you call it, what's happening now, are you getting any JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: no nothing get. how to get this in var data= ... this code... ? is this right?

Comment: @Lalit - no, this returns the XMLHttpRequest that gets the data...you need to call whatever function need the data when it comes back where you see `alert()` in the function above.  The callback function it's in runs *later* when the server comes back with data, this is just how AJAX works (it's unwise to go the synchronous route...it'll lock up the browser).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("Search")", $("#jsonform").serialize(), function (data) {
   $("#results").html("");
   $("#phoneTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#results");
   });
return false;
});
```

I use this code along with template plugin for jquery to get json data from an action and render it on the client.

are you hiting your action with ajax call?
do you construct your json with JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet set?

```
return Json(yourdata ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```